# Android Kotlin - registerForActivityResult pick image or video file

Tags: android, kotlin

Since startActivityForResult is deprecated I try to make the new method work.

This is how I pick a file (not tested yet because result code not ready):

```
    intent.type = "image/*"

    intent.putExtra(
        Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES,
        arrayOf("image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "video/mp4")
    )

    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
    getCommentMedia.launch(intent)
```

and this is how I try to receive it:

```
    val getCommentMedia = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        Log.d(tagg, "returned")
    
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            selectedFileUri = result.data
        }
    }
```

I get

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is Intent? but Uri? was expected
```

on

```
result.data
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()` returns an `intent` as a result. To get the `Uri` of the result data, call `data` method on the intent. See the below code:

```
val getCommentMedia = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        Log.d(tagg, "returned")
    
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            selectedFileUri = result.data?.data
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//for multiple images use the below

private var imagePickerResultActivityLauncher  = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetMultipleContents()){result ->
//Do whatever you want to do with the result. the result is a mutable list of Uri?
}

//for single Image use this
private var imagePickerResultActivityLauncher  = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()){result ->
//Do whatever you want to do with the result. the result is a Uri? 
}

//Launch it with this
imagePickerResultActivityLauncher.launch("image/*")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Compose and you want to pick an image or a video you can do the following creating a subclass of `ActivityResultContracts.GetContent`

```
class GetMediaActivityResultContract : ActivityResultContracts.GetContent() {

    override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: String): Intent {
        return super.createIntent(context, input).apply {
            // Force only images and videos to be selectable
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, arrayOf("image/*", "video/*"))
        }
    }
}
```

and then use it this way:

```
val pickMediaActivityResultLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = GetMediaActivityResultContract()
) { uri: Uri? ->
    //use the received Uri
}

Button(onClick = {
    pickMediaActivityResultLauncher.launch("*/*")
}) {
    Text(text = "Pick image or video")
}
```